# Reusing an HTTP connection in Android

Tags: android, http, connection, reusability

I am trying to re-use a connection in Android, and a quick google search finds this:
http://foo.jasonhudgins.com/2010/03/http-connections-revisited.html

However, I tried that, and if I use something like Wireshark, I can see I am still getting HTTP FIN-ACK after each of three consecutive calls, furthermore, the HTTP calls are going to different ports.

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Different ports to server or local outgoing ports? What do you mean by http calls are going to different ports? And what does matter if it goes through other ports as long as the connection is ESTABLISHED?

Comment: if the calls are going to different ports, then that isn't the same connection, right?  and HTTP FIN-ACK means the client has said it's finished with this connection....  or do I not understand that correctly?

Comment: Correct. Does this affects your application or is it against some requirements? Maybe the connection is closed(finished) due some residing time from the server, or any other reason. I think it is irrelevant as long your application or performances of your app are not affected :D

Comment: Well I think that's what I'm getting at.  If i could re-use the connection, then i could avoid the overhead of connecting.  I could avoid the DNS lookup and whatever else is required when establishing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a persistent connection to the server then you have to add a keep-alive request to your `URLConnection` object like so:

```
myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("connection", "Keep-Alive");
```

[See here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I actually verified that this works for URLConnection, but how do I do the equivalent of that using DefaultHttpClient / HTTPClient ?

Comment: httpclient.getConnectionManager().releaseConnection(conn, validDuration, timeUnit) you can specify for how long you want the connection alive